# Stata: rename variables by shifting suffixes

Tags: variables, rename, stata

I need to rename my variables `var1` to `var60` into `var2` to `var61` (i.e. doing +1 for the suffix of each variable, so that `var2` becomes `var3`, `var3` becomes `var4`...and so on).

I tried several things (`renvars`, `rename`), but I did not succeed and I am not very good at doing loops with `foreach`...

Comment: I think you should learn about arrays.

Comment: @tanaydin Question is about Stata. The title and the tags give that signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a two step approach

```
forvalues i =1/60{
rename var`i' var`=`i'+10'
}

forvalues i =11/70{
rename var`i' var`=`i'-9'
}
```

**Example with auto data:**

```
sysuse auto 
rename make var1
rename price var2
rename mpg var3
forvalues i =1/3{
    rename var`i' var`=`i'+10'
    }

forvalues i =11/13{
    rename var`i' var`=`i'-9'
    }
```

Comment: Glad that it worked and that will be useful to future users if you accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to go backwards:

```
 forval i = 60(-1)1 { 
     local j = `i' + 1 
     rename var`i' var`j' 
 }
```

This replaces two loops, as suggested by @Metrics, with one. Those paid by the reciprocal of the number of lines of code will want to go instead

```
 forval i = 60(-1)1 { 
     rename var`i' var`=`i' + 1' 
 }
```

Comment: Nice trick. I was trying to use one step with i in 1/60 but keep getting an error `var2 already defined` . So, I resorted to two step.

Comment: That's right. You can't rename `var1` to `var2` because `var2` exists. But if you rename `var60` to `var61` then the name `var60` becomes available, and so on.